# How can I verify the SSL certificate chain when uploading to Amazon/CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

We are using cloudfront to serve images with a custom domain.

```
http://images.example.com/fubar.png
```

We want to be able to access them with SSL, eg `https://images.example.com/fubar.png`

We have a wildcard SSL certificate (issued from Godaddy) for `*.example.com` and I used the **AWS Certificate Manager** to upload the certificate, private key, and keychain.  The upload appears to have been successful as `*.example.com` appears to be **issued** (according to the Certificate Manager).

I'm then following the instructions to [Update the CloudFront Distribution](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-procedures.html#cnames-and-https-updating-cloudfront) and I added `images.example.com`, selected the option for **Custom SSL Certificate** and made sure **Distribution State** was **enabled**. When I click the **Yes, Edit** button I get the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidViewerCertificateException: The specified SSL certificate doesn't exist, isn't in us-east-1 region, isn't valid, or doesn't include a valid certificate chain. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidViewerCertificate; Request ID: a62cf849-d495-11e7-94d9-673e2e2905b1)
```

I've used this SSL certificate elsewhere with success.  If it helps, I originally created this cert using a Windows machine to make the request and then downloaded the cert from Godaddy.  I don't have access to this download anymore, but I do have access to a PFX file on a Windows Server.  I took this PFX file (which has the private key) (named SSLWildcard.pfx) and used OpenSSL to get the certificate and private key.  I used the following commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in SSLWildcard.pfx -nocerts -out SSLWildcard.key
openssl rsa -in SSLWildcard.key -out SSLWildcard-decrypted.key
openssl pkcs12 -in SSLWildcard.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out SSLWildcard.crt
```

I used the contents of the CRT and KEY files (I used the decrypted key file) and GoDaddy's public certificate chain file `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`.  I've tried using various certs (and combinations) from [GoDaddy's public repository](https://certs.godaddy.com/repository) but I'm kind of just guessing.  Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: There's not much anyone can do without the real information. Perhaps someone in your company can help with the issue. Talk to your network admin or IT guys.

Answer (score 1):

The error message has one clue:  When using a cert for cloudfront, it must be in us-east-1.

You don't mention what region you uploaded the cert to, but if you're deploying to cloudfront make sure it's in us-east-1.

If the certificate is in us-east-1, there is one other clue:

```
 Error Code: InvalidViewerCertificate
```

If you are using an S3 bucket configured for public web hosting, you cannot communicate between cloudfront and s3 over https - it must be http.  See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-s3-origin.html) for details.

Comment: The certificate was uploaded to us-east-1

Comment: Hi @chris , but I've got also a certificate for eu-west-1 , I don't know why it has to be only for us-east-1